# Post message via slack api with file attachment

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I am trying to use Python SDK to post a file to Slack.
However, I am also trying to mention some people with `@` in the uploaded message.

I am trying this code:

```
import os
import slack
client = slack.WebClient(token='xoxp-asksjdfj')
res = client.files_upload(channels='#uploads', file='a.txt', title='@john')
```

However, the title doesn't show up as a mention.  Is there a way to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting your mention in `title`, you want to put it `initial_comment`.

```
res = client.files_upload(channels='#uploads', file='a.txt', initial_comment='@john')
```